# widgets not align in the bottom of a screen in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a screen like the below Screenshot. Which has a text in the centre of the screen and a button and text in the bottom of the screen, but I got both in the centre of the screen. I include my expected design, my code and my result below. Anyone, please help me. how to place the text in the centre of the screen and the remaining part inthe bottom of the screen.

Expected Screen,
[image: Expected Screen]

code:

```
 body: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new AssetImage("assets/images/home_page_background.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: new Container(
      child: new Column(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            // margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: _MARGIN_JAHMAIKA),
            child: new Text(
              'JAHMAIKA',
              style: style72,
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            // margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: _MARGIN_BUTTON),
            child: new FlatButton(
                child: new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: _PADDING_LARGE,
                      right: _PADDING_LARGE,
                      top: _PADDING_SMALL,
                      bottom: _PADDING_SMALL),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                        new Radius.elliptical(40.0, 50.0)),
                    border: new Border.all(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: new Text(
                    'Create an account',
                    style: style19,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => new SignUpPage()),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: _MARGIN_SMALL),
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: new Text(
                    'Already have an account?',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: style15White,
                  ),
                ),
                new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => new SignInPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: new Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: _MARGIN_SMALL),
                    child: new Text('Login',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: style15Green),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

result:
[image: result:]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could restructure you widgets inside the column in a different way.
You can use a column/container for all the buttons that has to be aligned to bottom and make the other widget as Expanded which takes up the remaining space, pushing the Row with the buttons to the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Comment: how can I fit the width of the button as same as the width of the button?

Comment: @RosemaryRajan, You can wrap it in a container with the container width set to `width: double.infinity`

Comment: any coding examples?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an Align widget wrapped with an Expanded widget to achieve width and height growth, like so:

```
Expanded(
  child: Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, 
    child: Containter(), // << Put your content here
 ),
```